# Утро или Ночь - помогите с этой проблемой

Tags: выбор-слов

У нас с женой разногласия: утро с какого часа начинается и до какого часа длится?

Comment: Это вопрос на тему русского языка? Тогда надо брать словарь: УТРО 1. Часть суток от окончания ночи до наступления дня; время восхода солнца, рассвета. НОЧЬ, - ж. Часть суток от захода до восхода солнца, от вечера до утра. Если нужна другая информация,  то вопрос не по теме, надо его закрыть.

Answer (score 2):

Традиционно ночь, утро, день и вечер делят следующим образом:
00:00-03:00 - ночь;
04:00-11:00 - утро;
12:00-15:00 - день;
16:00-23:00 - вечер.

Принято говорить:
"3 часа ночи", "4 часа утра";
"11 часов утра", "12 часов дня";
"11 часов вечера", "12 часов ночи" и т.д.
Документальных источников для подверждения я не встречал.

Comment: Вы мало того, что слишком опрометчиво уверяете, что принято говорить (кем, кому), так еще и диапазоны расставили "дырявые". 3:30 - это ночь или утро?!

Comment: Именно дырявые! Не додумался бы до такого слова, если б писал то же по смыслу. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант:

**У нас с женой разногласия: когда начинается и когда заканчивается утро?**

**Другие варианты:**

**Во сколько** начинается утро и **до скольких** оно продолжается?

**Во сколько** начинается утро и **до которого часа** оно продолжается?

О правильности использования местоимения "сколько"

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_68

Вопрос ***сколько времени?*** по сравнению с вопросом ***который час?*** новый. **Но он давно стал нормативным**. Он зафиксирован, например, уже в «Толковом словаре русского языка» под редакцией Дмитрия Николаевича Ушакова (М., 1935–1940). Интересно, что в этом издании вопрос *сколько времени?* дан как нейтральный, а вопрос *который час?* снабжен пометой «разговорное».

Если же вам необходимо спросить **о времени начала или окончания** работы магазина, учреждения, то вы задаете вопрос «В котором часу Вы открываете / закрываете магазин?» или **«Во сколько открывается / закрывается магазин?»**

И еще очень часто можно услышать распространенную ошибку Доскольки работает магазин? (Не знаем, как и написать это неправильное доскольки – такое слово в словарях русского языка не зафиксировано). Правильно: **до скольких работает магазин?** Или, в другой ситуации, до скольких ты будешь на работе? до скольких тебя ждать?.